# Jabber - xmpp conflict

Tags: xmpp, cisco, cucm

I'm building a custom Jabber connector (desktop app) for a bot developped internaly.

I can correctly authenticate my user to my Jabber Server through XMPP.
But when i want to perform a bind, the server always send me back a 409 conflict.

I've tried with pidgin and the cisco jabber SDK (https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/cisco-jabber-bot-sdk), it's the same 409 answer ...
My user is not connected anywhere else.

Yet the Cisco Jabber Client 11.8 is working well with my bot account (i can talk with him normally).

My company is using Cisco CUIMP 9.1 and might migrate to 11.5 at the end of the year.

Is there any configuration that shall be done on CUCM to pass the binding phase for a third party client ?

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of digging, I wasn't using the right domain in my JID. It's working fine now.